# How to handle Remote Attributes on Model Grid Edit? ASP.Net MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik, telerik-mvc

```
public class Page
{
 [Remote("CheckDuplicate", "Home", ErrorMessage = "Name already taken")]
 public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And In controller, I'm returning JsonResult data based on "Check" result as follows:

```
public JsonResult CheckDuplicate(string Name )
{
  var result = db.abc.Where(a => a.Name == Name ).Count() == 0;
  return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

This is working fine in when add new name , But problem is, It's restricting me to Edit , Since It's checking the same query.
I am using Telerik Grid ASP.NET MVC and using (GridEditMode.PopUp) method

Answer (score 0):

**make these modifications in your code.**

```
public class Page
{
    [DefaultValue(0)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Remote("CheckDuplicate", "Home", AdditionalFields = "ID", ErrorMessage = "Name already taken")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**And In controller**

```
public JsonResult CheckDuplicate(string Name, int Id)
{
  var result = db.abc.Where(a => (Id == 0) ? (a.Name == Name && a.ID != Id) : (a.Name == Name)).Count() == 0;
  return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

> Your can use more additional fields and separate them them by commas.
>   For example: AdditionalFields = "ID, ID2

"